# How to perform operation based on result of multiple RxJava Completable results

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java, rx-kotlin

Have been banging my head over this for a while, I am lost here in managing a requirement where I have to use Rx in Kotlin.

Let me explain.

There is a set of ids whose equivalent items needs to be deleted from server and eventually in local based on server success.

Basically

1. Make network call to delete for a single `id`(Supported network call returns a `Completable`)
2. if `complete`(success) callback is received store the `id` in a `list` (memory)
3. Do step one and two for all `id` to delete
4. Once every network call is complete pass the list to delete from local DB

So these functions are available which cannot be modified.

1. `fun deleteId(id: String): Completable { networkCall.deleteId(id) }`
2. `fun deleteIds(ids: List<String>): Unit { localDb.deleteId(ids) }`

This is what I have tried but obviously incomplete and stuck...

```kotlin
val deleted = CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>()
val error = CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>()
items?.filter { it.isChecked }
    ?.map { Pair(it.id, dataManager.deleteId(it.id)) }
    ?.forEach { (Id, deleteOp) ->
        deleteOp.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(object: CompletableObserver {
                    override fun onComplete() { deleted.add(Id) }

                    override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) { disposableManager += d }

                    override fun onError(e: Throwable) { error.add(Id) }

                })
    }
```

So now there are multiple problems here, One of them is the requirement where I am unable to find a place to know that all requests are completed so as to initiate a localDb delete.

Is there a way where I can use `Flowable.fromIterable()` or `zip` or `merge` somehow following the chain of commands like above to achieve the above scenario?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your use case correctly, then this should do:

```
// ids of items to delete, for illustration lets have some temp set
val ids = setOf<String>("1", "2", "3", "4")
val deleteIdSingles = mutableListOf<Single<String>>()
ids.forEach { id ->
    deleteIdSingles.add(
        api.deleteId(id)
            // when request successfully completes, return its id wrapped in a Single, instead of Completable
            .toSingle<String> { id }
            // return a flag when this request fails, so that the stream is not closed and other requests would still be executed
            .onErrorReturn { "FAILED" }
    )
}

Single.merge(deleteIdSingles)
    // collect the results of the singles (i.e. the ids of successful deletes), and emit a set of those ids once all the singles has completed
    .collect(
        { mutableListOf() },
        { deletedIds: MutableList<String>, id: String -> if (id != "FAILED") deletedIds.add(id) }
    )
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(
        { deletedIds ->
                db.deleteIds(deletedIds)
        }, { error ->
            // todo: onError
        })
```